# create new columns based on max values snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a table of restaurant sales. I want to identify which is the most common sale for each store and create new columns based on multiple max values.
My table is as follows:

| store_ id | Units_sold_Saturday | Units_sold_Sunday | Menu_Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X123 | 125 | 120 | Pie |
| X123 | 155 | 100 | Cheesecake |
| X123 | 100 | 125 | Brownie |
| X124 | 178 | 77 | Pasta |
| X124 | 90 | 10 | Ice cream |
| X124 | 90 | 15 | Pizza |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |

I want my data to look like the following- having one line for each store.

| store_ id | SaturdayItem | SundayItem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X123 | Cheesecake | Brownie |
| X124 | Pasta | pasta |

where the new column 'SaturdayItem' and new column 'SundayItem' contains the menu_item which sold the most units on that day

ive tried approaches such as

```
select distinct store_id, 
case when max(Units_sold_Saturday) then Menu_item end as 'SaturdayItem',
case when max(Units_sold_Sunday) then Menu_item end as 'SundayItem'
from table
```

but i get 'unexpected 'SaturdayItem' error.

Im wondering if i just need to create an empty table which lists all unique store_ids, create new empty columns 'Units_sold_Sunday' and 'Units_sold_Saturday'.
Im just unsure how i would grab the menu_item value rather than Units_sold value as this would be the result of max(Units_sold_Saturday).

thanks for your help

Comment: In case two items have the same value of units sold number (there is a tie in the max of units sold), which one should be chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [MAX_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by):

```
SELECT store_id, 
    MAX_BY(Menu_Item,Units_sold_Saturday) AS SaturdayItem,
    MAX_BY(Menu_Item,Units_sold_Sunday) AS Sunday
FROM tab
GROUP BY store_id
ORDER BY store_id;
```

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(store_id TEXT,
Units_sold_Saturday INT,
Units_sold_Sunday INT,
Menu_Item TEXT)
AS
          SELECT 'X123', 125    ,120    ,'Pie'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X123', 155    ,100    ,'Cheesecake'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X123', 100    ,125    ,'Brownie'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X124', 178    ,77     ,'Pasta'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X124', 90     ,10     ,'Ice cream'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X124', 90     ,15     ,'Pizza';
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTEs to create this logic.

I implemented this in a similar platform (Databricks using SQL) and this code can help you.

You only need to change the name of the table

```
with max_items as (
  select
    store_id,
    max(units_sold_saturday) max_units_sold_saturday,
    max(units_sold_sunday) max_units_sold_sunday
  from
    table
  group by
    store_id
)
select
  m.store_id,
  t_saturday.menu_item saturday_item,
  t_sunday.menu_item sunday_item
from
  max_items m
  join table t_saturday on m.store_id = t_saturday.store_id
  and m.max_units_sold_saturday = t_saturday.units_sold_saturday
  join table t_sunday on m.store_id = t_sunday.store_id
  and m.max_units_sold_sunday = t_sunday.units_sold_sunday
```

Here is my return.

[image]

Comment: thank you this is very helpful! my only issue with matching on store id and units is that some items will have the same number of units for a store. so if 2 products are max i would want only one to be returned (doesnt matter which) but currently i obtain lots of duplicates!

Comment: HI , you can try using Distinct and see if it helps, SELECT distinct  store_id,
    max(units_sold_saturday) max_units_sold_saturday,
    max(units_sold_sunday) max_units_sold_sunday

Comment: thanks, the issue comes in the second part- i dont get any dups in the first bit, but if a store has the same number of units for 2 products the join results in a dup when joining on the unit_sold variable!